# Problems installing openvpn client Permission denied (23) and ERROR 404: Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, curl, installation, vpn, openvpn

**Command Step 1:**

sudo curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg

Following error message:

bash: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-pkg-keyring.gpg: Permission denied
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
(23) Failed writing body

**Command Step 2:**
curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-$DISTRO.list >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list

Following error message:

bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list: Permission denied

**Other Command Step 3:**

sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list  https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-$DISTRO.list

Following error message:

--2022-11-09 07:06:29--  https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-.list
Resolving swupdate.openvpn.net (swupdate.openvpn.net)... 104.18.109.96, 104.18.110.96
Connecting to swupdate.openvpn.net (swupdate.openvpn.net)|104.18.109.96|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-11-09 07:06:29 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

**Step 1:**

```
sudo wget https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub

sudo apt-key add openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
```

**Step 2:**

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-$DISTRO.list
```

If the following command failed HTTP request sent, awaiting

```
response... 404 Not Found, ERROR 404: Not Found.

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

Then: so what you should do is

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-$(lsb_release -sc).list
wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-groovy.list
```

**Step 3:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openvpn3
```